# Compare current date with future date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, time

I am trying to compare the current date in the following format (ddmmyyyy) to a future date in the following format (ddmmyyyy)

I put them in that format so i can easily compare them as integers. However, it keeps failing the if then test.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

StartDay=datetime.today()  # Get current date in this format 2020-04-28 19:59:16.901897

EndDay=StartDay+timedelta(60) # I want to be able to add 60 days to StartDay 

print(EndDay.strftime('%d%m%Y')) # Print EndDay as an integer 27062020

EndDay=EndDay.strftime('%d%m%Y') # Convert EndDay to make it look like an integer

StartDay=datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%Y') # Convert the StartDay to make it look like an integer

if int(StartDay)>int(EndDay):
    print('Game Over!')
else:
    pass
```

What I want to achieve is the an integer value for a date, such that the future date will always be greater than past/current date if that makes sense.

Comment: Just use this format `'%Y%m%d'`. You want your format to be in an order of importance, from largest to smallest. Otherwise, your `EndDay` day will always be smaller, since 60 days is slightly less than 2 months in most if not all cases.

Comment: There is a serious flaw in your design. *Every time* you run this, `StartDay` will be set to *the current date*, and so `EndDay` cannot ever be reached.

Comment: You should do the comparison when `StartDay` and `EndDay` are both still `datetime` objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly compare `datetime` objects, no need for a detour here:

```
from datetime import datetime
t0, t1 = datetime(2020,1,1), datetime(2020,1,2)

t0>t1
Out[6]: False

t0<t1
Out[7]: True

t1-t0
Out[8]: datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: I don't think that what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Anwarvic, I know, the example just didn't fit nicely in a comment. Also, given the fact the OP wanted to compare ddmmyyyy points to a bit of a flaw in the logic, so why not suggest a different approach.

Comment: But I need to compare current date to future date and if current date is greater/passed it will print out some thing.

Comment: The OP wanted to compare the two dates, but the way they were doing it (based on the string representation) doesn't make sense when they've used `datetime` objects to get there. In this case, is it not better to provide a solution that achieves their intended goal, rather than strictly work within the parameters they've articulated?

Comment: @AlanJones: the point is you should compare `datetime` objects, as Andrew's comment under your question says.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for that, I thought I could convert a datetime object into an integer so I can easily compare the two.

Comment: @AlanJones: I'd suggest to avoid conversions if you dont *have* to do them. Also, if you want to work with numeric representations of date/time, use POSIX timestamps, which you can e.g. obtain by the `timestamp()` method of the `datetime` class.

Comment: @MrFuppes I'll keep a note of POSIX timestamps in the future. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.datetime` might be easily converted into `datetime.date` and then compared consider following example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
StartDay = datetime.today()
EndDay = StartDay + timedelta(60)
StartDate = StartDay.date()  # datetime.date(2020, 4, 28)
EndDate = EndDay.date()  # datetime.date(2020, 6, 27)
print(StartDate < EndDate)  # True
```

Note that you might also compare `datetime.datetime` directly with `datetime.datetime` but this take in account also units smaller than days, so if you have two `datetime.datetime`s say `d1` and `d2` with same year-month-day but different hours, then result of `d1 < d2` might be different from `d1.date() < d2.date()`

Comment: Is this accurate for dates that are far apart? eg 100 days? 300 days etc?

Comment: @AlanJones: what do you mean under *accurate* in this case?

Comment: I mean reliable. Eg if i compare say todays date with a date 100 days from today. Will it return true?

Comment: @AlanJones: why shouldn't it? At least, the [`datetime` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Doc/library/datetime.rst) is part of the Python standard library...

Comment: Wouldn't this always calculate the current date and future date so that way, it will never return false. Am i missing something in my logic?

Comment: What I am trying to say is the `startday` needs to be fixed in order for us to compare it to the `end day`

Answer (score 1):

Keep startdate and enddate as 'datetime' and do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
StartDay=datetime.today()
EndDay=StartDay+timedelta(60) 
delta = (StartDay - EndDay).days
if delta > 0:
    print('Game Over!')
else:
    print('Something else')
```

This should do the trick